# mx.DataGrid: How to force scroll to the right end programmatically?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I'm trying to scroll mx.DataGrid programmatically.
In [that case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31672194/how-to-pagescroll-mx-datagrid-programmatically), I did force scroll to the right end by following code.

```
grid.horizontalScrollPosition = grid.maxHorizontalScrollPosition;
```

But in some cases, maxHorizontalScrollPosition returns incorrect value.
It seems the maxHorizontalScrollPosition is calculated value depend on grid width and columns width, and sometimes wrong.
Following code is the reproducible test case.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" creationComplete="init()">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

            private var arr:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
                {COL1:"aaa",COL2:"bbb",COL3:"ccc",COL4:"ddd",COL5:"eee",COL6:"fff",COL7:"ggg",COL8:"hhh",COL9:"iii",COL10:"jjj",COL11:"kkk",COL12:"lll",COL13:"mmm",COL14:"nnn",COL15:"ooo",COL16:"ppp",COL17:"qqq",COL18:"rrr",COL19:"sss",COL20:"ttt",COL21:"uuu",COL22:"vvv",COL23:"www"}
            ]);
            public function init(): void
            {
                grid.dataProvider = arr;
            }

            public function doScroll(): void
            {
                // this doesn't scroll to the right end sometimes.
                grid.horizontalScrollPosition = grid.maxHorizontalScrollPosition;
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:Button click="{doScroll()}" label="Scroll to right"/>
    <mx:DataGrid id="grid" y="30" width="1000" horizontalScrollPolicy="on">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="COL1" dataField="COL1" width="70"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="COL2" dataField="COL2" width="210"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="COL3" dataField="COL3" width="80"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="COL4" dataField="COL4" width="100"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="COL5" dataField="COL5" width="25"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="COL6" dataField="COL6" width="25"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="COL7" dataField="COL7" width="25"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="COL8" dataField="COL8" width="70"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="COL9" dataField="COL9" width="55"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="COL10" dataField="COL10" width="160"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="COL11" dataField="COL11" width="25"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="COL12" dataField="COL12" width="25"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="COL13" dataField="COL13" width="25"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="COL14" dataField="COL14" width="25"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="COL15" dataField="COL15" width="25"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="COL16" dataField="COL16" width="25"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="COL17" dataField="COL17" width="25"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="COL18" dataField="COL18" width="100"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="COL19" dataField="COL19" width="150"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="COL20" dataField="COL20" width="100"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="COL21" dataField="COL21" width="150"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="COL22" dataField="COL22" width="100"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="COL23" dataField="COL23" width="100"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
</mx:Application>
```

What is the correct way to force scroll to the right end?
I'm using Flex SDK3.4.

**Updated:** Sep 17 15:28(JST)
As far as I saw "override protected function configureScrollBars()"(defined at DataGrid.as), it seems that maxHorizontalScrollPosition is computed by

```
maxHorizontalScrollPosition = displayableColumns.length - lockedColumnCount - colCount;
```

In my case

```
displayableColumns.length(Columns with visible="true")  = 23
lockedColumnCount  = 0
colCount = visibleColumns.length = 17 (sum of COL1 ~ COL17 width is 995)
```

So initial value of maxHorizontalScrollPosition returns certainly 6.
Whenever I move scrollThumb somewhere, visibleColumns.length and maxHorizontalScrollPosition also changes depended on position of scrollThumb.

hmm.. that means I should not use maxHorizontalScrollPosition.
But what is the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated: March 1 2016**

The previous answer works sometimes wrong...
Finally I gave up to calculate maxHorizontalScrollPosition.

The solution I'm using now is following code.

```
while (grid.horizontalScrollPosition < grid.maxHorizontalScrollPosition-grid.lockedColumnCount){
    grid.horizontalScrollPosition = grid.maxHorizontalScrollPosition-grid.lockedColumnCount;
}
```